# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{f(n)}}{n}$ where $f(n)$ is the number of prime divisors

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

> Let $f(n)$ be the number of prime divisors of a number $n$ counted with their multiplicities. Show that the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{f(n)}}{n}$ converges and has sum $0$.

Attempt :
The infinite product $$\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1+\frac1p\right)^{-1}$$ diverges to zero.

and we have,
$$\left(1+\frac1p\right)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{p^{k}}$$

Formally we can write : $$\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{p^{k}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{f(n)}}n$$

Unfortunatly I do not see how can I  make this rigourous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no simple rigorous proof. The situation is the same as proving $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0,$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function ($\mu(1)=1$; $\mu(n)=(-1)^s$ if $n$ is a product of distinct primes $p_1,\ldots, p_s$ and $\mu(n)=0$ otherwise). For this one needs to use inverse formula for the corresponding Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$
(such as [Perron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula)). This is as hard as the prime number theorem! (In fact, even equivalent to it.) Detailed proof you can find, for example, in the book [Titchmarsh E.C. The theory of the Riemann zeta-function](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/The%20Theory%20Of%20The%20Riemann%20Zeta-Function%20-Titshmarch.pdf) (section 3.13).

The same can be done for the Dirichlet series generating function of your sequence: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{f(n)}}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}$$
and you'll get the desired proof.

Another approach is to use the following result.

**Theorem**. Suppose that the series $$F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s}$$ is absolutely convergent for $\Re s>0$, $F(s)$ is regular for $s=0$ and $a_n=O(\frac1n)$. Then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ is convergent and has sum $F(0)$.

(See the book: R. Ayoub, An Introduction to the Analytic Theory of Numbers, chapter II, problems 29-31.) Proving this theorem isn't much easier though.

Comment: How can we use the second theorem to prove the result ?

Comment: Just set $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{f(n)}}{n}$, then $F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(2s+2)}{\zeta(s+1)}$ converges absolutely for $\Re s>0$, regular for $s=0$ (since $\lim_{s\to0}F(s)=0$) and $|a_n|\leq\frac1n$, so $\sum a_n=F(0)=0$.

Comment: Right!! Very nice answer. +1